# applicationDidFinishLaunching - anyway to get this using script/command?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

Is there a way to detect when an app has finished launching after using `open <path_to_app>` in a shell? The prompt after issuing the command is immediate, but for apps that take a while to fully launch will timeout events until fully launched…

Using `ps aux | grep -i 'path to app' | grep -v grep | wc -l`, returns a process ID almost immediately (at app launch time), so no good.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: 'top' command doesn't seem to yield different response to either opening / launched state either.

Comment: Put another way, you are testing to see if the application is accepting events from the event queue. This is the same signal that determines if an application is deemed frozen/unresponsive by macOS. Is it possible to determine if an application is unresponsive on macOS? Via `spindump` maybe?

Comment: See [How can I determine if an application is not responding?](https://superuser.com/questions/688024/how-can-i-determine-if-an-application-is-not-responding) for alternative approaches.

Comment: This really is turning out to get a tough one, for something that ought to be so easy - I mean... the icon bounces in the dock until it's fully finished launching... you'd think there might be a way to query what the dock is up to...

Comment: Resolved by monitoring STATE column for application bundle using TOP. Wait for STATE to change to 'sleeping' for a couple of seconds did the trick (for me anyway).

Comment: Please could you mention your approach in an answer. That will mark this question as having an answer and hopefully help others with the same problem in the future.

Comment: You can also create command line util that listens to NSWorkspaceNoticication https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1524783-didlaunchapplicationnotification

Answer (score 2):

Resolved by monitoring STATE column for application bundle using TOP. Wait for STATE to change to 'sleeping' for a couple of seconds did the trick (for me anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can create commandline tool using Swift. Here's the sample code:

```
import AppKit

let timeout: TimeInterval = 5.0

let appToLaunch = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.dropFirst().joined(separator: " ")
let runningApps = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications.map { $0.localizedName }

if runningApps.contains(appToLaunch) {
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
}

NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(forName: NSWorkspace.didLaunchApplicationNotification,
                                                  object: nil,
                                                  queue: nil) { (notification) in
    guard let appName = notification.userInfo?["NSApplicationName"] as? String
        else { return }
    if appName == appToLaunch {
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
    }
}

let exitTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeout, repeats: false) { _ in
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
}

RunLoop.current.run()
```

Pass the app name as an argument to it. For example: `./listener Mini Calendar`

It checks if the app is already running.
You can also set different `timeout` if you want.